# Write a command that lists the unique values (remember, name/value pairs) that are actually set (i.e. ignore commented lines)

Tags: linux, unix

The /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf file contains a number of name, value pairs of the form “name = value”.  It also contains a number of other things including headers, in which the line starts with a [, and comments, which have a # as the first character.  Write a command that lists the unique values (remember, name/value pairs) that are actually set (i.e. ignore commented lines).

Yes this is a homework question but I do not know what I am doing and was hoping someone could help or give me an example of something that could work so I can have a better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Check out `awk` for questions that require you to go line by line, parsing the line, and making decisions on what get's outputted. For example:

```
awk -F"[= \t]+" '$0 ~ /^[^#\r\n\t \[]/ {print $1, $2}' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

awk moves through files line by line. We first specify a delimiter to split each line into tokens using the `-F` flag. Here we split lines into multiple tokens using `=`, , or tab `\t` occurring one or many times in a row (`-F"[= \t]+"`).

Then in the awk script itself we have blocks where we take action on each line encountered. Blocks occur between squiggly brackets `{ this is a block }`. We can refer to each split off token using the dollar sign and a number starting at 1. `$1` means the first token encountered. Here our block that is executed on each line is `{print $1, $2}` which says "Print out the first and second token encountered for this line", which is the stuff before the equal sign and the stuff directly after.

Furthermore, a block can be made conditional by putting a conditional statement right before it that returns true or false. Here we use a regex condition on the special token `$0` which means the entire line's content: `$0 ~ /^[^#\r\n\t \[]/` That says: "If the line doesn't start with a `#`, carriage return, line feed, tab, space, or `[` character, then execute the block for this line.

You can specify the character that you would like to seperate your key/value pairs using awks built in `OFS` variable in a special `BEGIN{}` block, which is executed once before the file processing begins:

```
 awk -F"[= \t]+" 'BEGIN{OFS="|"} $0 ~ /^[^#\r\n\t \[]/ {print $1, $2}' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

With that you'll get a pipe delimiter between your key/value pair from the config file.

One caveat here, values of the key/value pair that have delimiters in them will be truncated, so a [for loop](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/For-Statement.html) in the awk script may be needed to iterate through your tokens starting at `$2` until you hit a token that matches that `/^[^#\r\n\t \[]/` may be needed to collect all the bits of the value.